# Coredata fetch request using NSPredicate

Tags: core-data, fetch

I want to do a phone number search in sqlite db. Phone table have a number field which holds a string value (eg: +1 (2-34)56-78 ).

If user enters search text as "234", then I need to fetch the phone numbers with only digits(eliminating all other alphabets or special characters in the string stored) using `NSPredicate` and compare it with the entered string. Should I do this using a predicate in a fetch request?

I tried with following predicate and it doesn't return me the expected result:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"contactName != null AND SUBQUERY(phoneList, $phone, ANY $phone.number CONTAINS[c] %@).@count > 0",searchText];
```

IS there any way to get this done? Can I use regular expression with `NSPredicate` for this?

Comment: Does a phone have one number or is number a to-many relationship?

Comment: Phone table have two fields: number and label. A contact can have many phone numbers. So here 'phoneList' is the many relationship of the Contact  to the phone table . Im trying to fetch contacts with the search string as the phone number.

Comment: SUBQUERY and ANY are both handling a to-many relationship. Try format `"contactName != null AND ANY phoneList.number CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText`.

Comment: Thank you. I corrected it. But doing this doesn't show me the phone number with special characters in the result list. I need to remove special characters from the column value and do comparison with only the digits.

Comment: You can use `MATCHES` and a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

`NSPredicate` doesn't support that kind of matching. Your Core Data model should include data that your app requires for filtering-- which might mean extra fields that are not normally visible to users. If you need to match numbers without regard to non-numeric characters, you should add a field which contains that data. If the actual string is `+1 (2-34)56-78`, add a secondary field where you store `12345678`. Use this extra field in the predicate.